# intuitive explanation of the shrinkage of coefficients in logistic regression with omitted regressors

Tags: logistic, generalized-linear-model

In logistic regression, when one omits a relevant regressor, the estimates of the coefficients of the other regressors are affected in that they're shrunk, see [Mood 2010](https://academic.oup.com/esr/article-abstract/26/1/67/540767?redirectedFrom=fulltext)

This phenomenon is easily interpreted when looking at logistic regression as a latent factor model where one estimates the logit + logistic distribution with scale parameter 1. Essentially, by omitting a factor, the noise of the latent factor increases and has to be rescaled to 1, forcing a shrinkage of the coefficient estimates.

But I struggle to find an intuitive explanation when looking at logistic regression as a GLM, i.e. probabilities as sigmoidal link function of the regressors and Bernoulli trials. Is there a simple explanation?

I guess that the crucial point is that the variance of a Bernoulli trial is fully determined by its mean, but it still falls short of explaining the shrinkage.